# Add a filter to my view before executing

Tags: 7, views

I have a view and I want to get it's results.

```
$nview = views_get_view('tasks');
$nview->set_display('page');
$nview->pre_execute();
$nview->execute();
```

If I have 'nid' filter added to my view, I can **modify** it and get my view filtered.

```
$nview = views_get_view('tasks');
$nview->set_display('page');
$nview->pre_execute();
$nview->display['page']->handler->handlers['filter']['nid']->value['value']=180;
$nview->display['page']->handler->handlers['filter']['nid']->operator='=';
$nview->execute();
```

But what do I need write to **add** a filter **if no filter present in view settings** of my view?

```
$nview = views_get_view('tasks');
$nview->set_display('page');
$nview->pre_execute();

//some code here

$nview->execute();
```

UPD: Unfortunately, I can't use hook_views_query_alter because I need to use my code in my custom function which accepts view's name as an argument.
My target is to alter any view which name passed as an argument to my custom function.
So I need to alter filter/query only if I need get view's result and the view executes from my function. But if the view executes from it's page or block it needs to be executed without altering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way is to add the filter as an exposed filter in the view and then set it programmatically like this:

```
// Set created date range filter.
$item = $view->get_item($display_id, 'filter', 'created');
$item['value']['min'] = $settings['min'];
$item['value']['max'] = $settings['max'];
// Disable exposed filter in UI, for programmatic filter.
$item['exposed'] = FALSE;  
$view->set_item($display_id, 'filter', 'created', $item);
```

That should come *before* `$view->pre_execute();`

You can also add a completely new filter in a similar way, by building up a valid `$item` to use with `$view->set_item`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a filter on your view when it is not defined in the view UI you can use [hook_views_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7)

Something like this:

```
function MYMODULE_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  dpm($view, __FUNCTION__);
  dpm($query, __FUNCTION__);
  if ($view->name === 'your_view_machine_name') {
    // Alter query.
    $query->where....
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately your solution is not good for me. Please read UPD in my question.